# innerHTML not working properly in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I am setting the value of a form field using javascript. Now when I select the HTML content of that field using innerHTML the value gets disappeared. 
Here is the code.

```js
function test() {
  document.getElementById("fname").value = "Deepak";
}

function test2() {
  alert(document.getElementById("testform").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<form id="testform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="test()">
<input type="button" value="Show Inner HTML" onclick="test2()">
```

I can not use jquery in this , so have to do it using JS only.
The output should be `<input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" value="Deepak">`
But currently it shows, `<input name="fname" id="fname" type="text">`

Any workaround to solve this issue? This works fine on IE.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Field value changes aren't necessarily reflected in their DOM attributes.

Comment: @JLRishe: After setting the value of the field to `Deepak` why innerHTML  does not fetches it?

Comment: Input values are not part of the HTML. The HTML only contains the original value, not modified values.

Comment: If you want to change the value in the HTML, use `.setAttribute('value', 'Deepak')`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks a lot . It now works as expected. you saved my day.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy The question remains _why_ you are trying to do this. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Barmar may have given you code that gives you the result you are expecting, but it still sounds like you are going about your task the wrong way. BTW, neither IE 11 nor FireFox include the value in the `innerHTML` with your original code, so this is not browser specific, at least not with modern browsers.

Comment: @Barmar: Could you please help me to understand the difference between setting the value using `document.getElementById("fname").value = "Deepak"` and `document.getElementById("fname").setAttribute('value', 'Deepak');`

Comment: @JLRishe: I am working on an old IE application to make it compatible with firefox . That particular application sends `innerHTML` content of a form to a modal popup plugin after setting the form field values,which is what not working in firefox.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy Can you show us the code you are using to show the modal popup and tell us what plugin you are using? Getting that to work correctly is the problem to solve. How to get form values to show up in `innerHTML` is probably not a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: @JLRishe I am using https://github.com/okonet/modalbox/blob/master/modalbox.js but an older version of this. The JS code is complete Here is a small snippet `Modalbox.show(document.getElementById('RAForm').innerHTML, {title: 'Create RA', width:700});`

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy `.setAttribute()` sets the attribute in the DOM element. `.value=` sets the value property, which is equivalent to the user typing into the input.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing in FireFox is the correct behavior. Changing the value of an input should not change its `value` attribute (if it even has one). Newer versions of IE will behave the same way as FireFox does, and older versions of IE have a bug on which your code was relying. You can see this in the [DOM level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485):

> Changing [the `value` property] changes the contents of the form control, but does not change the value of the HTML value attribute of the element.

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to pass a DOM node directly to `Modalbox.show()`:

```
Modalbox.show(document.getElementById('RAForm'), {title: 'Create RA', width:700});
```

So please try that. I believe that should solve your issue.